# asp.net dispose inside a class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before return dt i want destroy sda

How destroy an Object with Dispose - inside the class dbConnect ?

```
  public class dbConnect
    {

    // othee code 

    public DataTable SetQuery(string constr, DataTable dt, string sSql)
        {              
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                //sda = null
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                        }

                        finally
                        {
                            if (sda != null)
                                sda.Dispose();
                            //why the sda is not = null ?
                        }

                        return dt;
                    }             
            }              
        }
```

What is the correct procedure for destroy object (not class) ?

Comment: The Command is also disposable so you may want to implement `IDisposable` on your class anyway even though you are already handling the connection and data adapter. But, I don't see where the command is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

Since you make use of the `using` statement for `sda`, the Dispose would be called under the hood once you don't need it anymore.

For further info please have look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Answer (score 3):

- Using `Dispose()` doesn't mean your variable will become `null`, it's
  you who chooses wheither your variable should stop referencing
  something (so it's you who must set it to `null`).
- You don't need to call `Dispose()` when you use `using` on a variable,
  it will be called automatically at the end (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).